# Navigation inside tab in android

Tags: android, tabs, navigation

I have a tab activity, which contains 4 tabs and each one contain activities.  In the fourth tab i have got a list activity. it will list a number of options. when we click and option it will go to another activity.  and when i press back button from that activity the application exits. But actually i want to go back to the list of options.

Can any body help me to get rid of this

Regards
Pramod

Answer (score 0):

Override the back button with this code

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

 //Enter code here telling it what you want to do when you hit back

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Override the onPause() of the Activity you mentioned above "when we click and option it will go to another activity" to go to the Activity of the Tab containing the options via Intent with its class.

Answer (score 0):

Use getParent() to the activity & use the below to so that you will be able add up view by clearing up existing views & adding new views to the top.

```
Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

Answer (score 0):

All the tabs reside inside the activity, so when the backkey has been pressed the complete activity goes into background, so if you want to navigate to a particular activity override the onkeydown method and navigate to the particular tab

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    MyActivity mMyActivity;
    mMyActivity = (MyActivity) this.getParent();
    mMyActivity.switchTab(tabnumber);
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }
```